# Multiple file upload then crop and resize using image magician

Tags: php, file-upload, image-manipulation

I've googled and googled but can't seem to find a way to have a multiple file upload then crop/resize each image. I'm using image magician for my single file uploads and it works great!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

p.s this is in PHP

Comment: Can you show us the code of the single file upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling multiple files shouldn't be that different than handling a single one.

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='upload.php'>
    <p>Files: <input name="images[]" multiple="multiple" type="file" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Your PHP might look as follows:

```
foreach($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['images']['size'][$key];
    $fileTmp = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $fileType = $_FILES['images']['type'][$key];
    ...
}
```